# AttributeError at /accounts/upload_save/ 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,AttributeError at /accounts/upload_save/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data' .I am making file upload system.It is that if i select file and put "SEND" button,selected image is sent to model.But now,when i select images and put "SEND" button,the error happens.
I wrote in views.py

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):
    form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.image = request.cleaned_data['image']
            data.save()
            return render(request, 'photo.html')

    else:
        form = UserImageForm()
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

in index.html

```
<main>
    <div class="detailimg col-xs-8">
        <div class="relative_ele">

            <div class="container" id="photoform">
                {% if form.errors %}　
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    　<p>At least 1 picture should be selected</p>　　
                </div>
                {% endif %}

                <form action="/accounts/upload_save/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="input-group-btn" style="width: 80px;">
                            <span class="file_select btn-lg">
                                File Select1
                                <input type="file" name="image">
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">　　
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="input-group-btn" style="width: 80px;">
                            <span class="btn-lg file_select">
                            File Select2
                            <input type="file" name="image2">
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">　　
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens.I reworte in views.py like

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            data.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserImageForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/photo.html', {'form': form})
```

but same error happens.How should i fix this?Which point is WSGIRequest in my code?

Answer (score 0):

`request.cleaned_data['image']` is invalid, you should use `form.cleaned_data` as in your second example.

If you get the same `AttributeError`, then you have not restarted your server and are still running the old code.

You probably don't need the `data.image = form.cleaned_data['image']` line at all. The model form will take care of setting the image field. After saving with `commit=False`, you only need to change fields that were not included in the form.

```
if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        data = form.save(commit=False)
        data.user = request.user
        data.save()
```